# Failing to build because of _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I think it might have to do with where  I am saving it and builds. Here are my errors: 
These never happened before and they are probably more related to where I am building?

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in main.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate dealloc] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController dealloc] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController dealloc] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController dealloc] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController dealloc] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController dealloc] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController dealloc] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController dealloc] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController dealloc] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController dealloc] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController viewDidUnload] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController dealloc] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController dealloc] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController dealloc] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController dealloc] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController dealloc] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController dealloc] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController dealloc] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController dealloc] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController dealloc] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController viewDidUnload] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController dealloc] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController dealloc] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController dealloc] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController dealloc] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController dealloc] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController dealloc] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController viewDidUnload] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController dealloc] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in WinnerViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController viewDidUnload] in WinnerViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController dealloc] in WinnerViewController.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate dealloc] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate dealloc] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController Q1] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController Q1] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController Q1] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController QSkip] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController QSkip] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[StupidQuizViewController QSkip] in StupidQuizViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q3] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q3] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q3] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q2lose] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q2lose] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2ViewController Q2lose] in Q2ViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController restart] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController restart] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q2WrongViewController restart] in Q2WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q4] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q4] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q4] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q3lose] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q3lose] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3ViewController Q3lose] in Q3ViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController restart] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController restart] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q3WrongViewController restart] in Q3WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q5] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q5] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q5] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q4lose] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q4lose] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4ViewController Q4lose] in Q4ViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController restart] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController restart] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q4WrongViewController restart] in Q4WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q6] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q6] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q6] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q5lose] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q5lose] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5ViewController Q5lose] in Q5ViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController restart] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController restart] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q5WrongViewController restart] in Q5WrongViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController restart] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController restart] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1LoseViewController restart] in Q1LoseViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q2] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q2] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q2] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q1lose] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q1lose] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q1ViewController Q1lose] in Q1ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q7] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q7] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q7] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q6lose] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q6lose] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6ViewController Q6lose] in Q6ViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController restart] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController restart] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q6WrongViewController restart] in Q6WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q8] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q8] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q8] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q7lose] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q7lose] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7ViewController Q7lose] in Q7ViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController restart] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController restart] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q7WrongViewController restart] in Q7WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q9] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q9] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q9] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q8lose] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q8lose] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8ViewController Q8lose] in Q8ViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController restart] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController restart] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q8WrongViewController restart] in Q8WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q10] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q10] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q10] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q9lose] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q9lose] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9ViewController Q9lose] in Q9ViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController restart] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController restart] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q9WrongViewController restart] in Q9WrongViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController next] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController next] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController next] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController wrong] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController wrong] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q11ViewController wrong] in Q11ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController next] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController next] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController next] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController wrong] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController wrong] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q12ViewController wrong] in Q12ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController next] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController next] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController next] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController wrong] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController wrong] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q13ViewController wrong] in Q13ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController next] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController next] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController next] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController wrong] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController wrong] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q14ViewController wrong] in Q14ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController next] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController next] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController next] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController wrong] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController wrong] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q10ViewController wrong] in Q10ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController next] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController next] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController next] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController wrong] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController wrong] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[Q15ViewController wrong] in Q15ViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController restart] in WinnerViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController restart] in WinnerViewController.o
      -[WinnerViewController restart] in WinnerViewController.o
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizViewController in StupidQuizViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2ViewController in Q2ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q2WrongViewController in Q2WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3ViewController in Q3ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q3WrongViewController in Q3WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4ViewController in Q4ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q4WrongViewController in Q4WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5ViewController in Q5ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q5WrongViewController in Q5WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1LoseViewController in Q1LoseViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q1ViewController in Q1ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6ViewController in Q6ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q6WrongViewController in Q6WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7ViewController in Q7ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q7WrongViewController in Q7WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8ViewController in Q8ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q8WrongViewController in Q8WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9ViewController in Q9ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q9WrongViewController in Q9WrongViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q11ViewController in Q11ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q12ViewController in Q12ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q13ViewController in Q13ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q14ViewController in Q14ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q10ViewController in Q10ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Q15ViewController in Q15ViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_WinnerViewController in WinnerViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_StupidQuizAppDelegate in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
  "_objc_setProperty", referenced from:
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate setViewController:] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
      -[StupidQuizAppDelegate setWindow:] in StupidQuizAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: 20 hours is not what I would call a very long development time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fails on linking against the Cocoa frameworks. Have you possibly removed UIKit.framework and Foundation.framework from your project?
You should have them in your 'Frameworks' Category/Folder in Xcode and in your Target they have to be in 'Link Binary With Libraries'

Comment: You are amazing, It just built and ran!  <3

Comment: You're welcome! It makes me happy to help others. No need to pay me for that.

Comment: @Praveen S gift? sry I don't get it?